# Setting padding in Tooltips

Tags: css, angularjs

There are many tooltips all over the project and a common CSS file.

Main.css:

```
/* Tooltip container */ .uibTooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; }

/* Tooltip text */ .uibTooltip .uibTooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

   /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;

   /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s; }

/* Tooltip arrow */ .uibTooltip .uibTooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:  -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent; }

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */ .uibTooltip:hover .uibTooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1; }
```

Usage in Angular templates:

```
<span class="uibTooltip">
 <i style="font-size:13px" class="fa">&#xf05a;</i>
  <span class="uibTooltiptext">Sample Tag</span>
</span>
```

But for different texts, Different paddings are being shown in the tooltips. Some are perfect, while other texts are just on the border.

Comment: You placing padding in top and bottom, you can try but adding all side in ".uibTooltip .uibTooltiptext { padding: 5px;}. Let appy if it is work for you.

Comment: @Hanif: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS `padding: 5px 0;` is inverted, the first is for the top/bottom so you don't set a left and right padding. It works in some cases because you set a widht to 120px.

So you should invert your padding to  `padding: 0 5px;` or use full padding in four sides : `padding: 5px;` and trandform your `width: 120px;` to `min-width: 120px;` or delete it if you want the same padding all the time.

Comment: Thanks! It works great. One more thing though, how to get the width to adjust automatically according to text?

Comment: If you want the width to adjust automatically, just delete the property width.